# How can I clone git branch with submodule?

Tags: git, github, branch, local, git-submodules

I have a branch called A (not main branch) and there's some files and one submodule. I want to clone this submodule to my local repository but I don't know how to.

I tried some commands but they only cloned files and folders. They only copy the folder of the submodule, except the files and folders inside it.

Here are some commands I tried but they didn't work.

```
git clone --recurse-submodules -b week3 --single-branch git://github.com/foo/bar.git
git clone -b week3 --single-branch git://github.com/foo/bar.git
```

How can I clone a submodule in a specific branch(not main) to my local computer?

Comment: You don't really clone branches in the first place: you clone *commits*. The `-b` option tells Git which *new name* to *create* once the clone finishes. The `--single-branch` option limits how many / which commits you copy and what remote-tracking names your Git creates based on the commits it copied. In any case, submodules don't use branches at all: they use raw commit hash IDs.

Comment: The default for `git clone` is to copy all the commits, and turn all of the other repository's commits into remote-tracking names. A submodule clone (as started by `--recurse-submodules` or `git submodule update --init`) clones the submodule in the default way but disables the creation of any branch at all, since the superproject will then check out a commit by raw hash ID.